# Folder Security Permission corrupted

Tags: windows, security, permissions, directory

i m using windows server 2003, in which the AD was corrupted. now i m moved to new server but my files and folders security permission was corrupted. every folder file i have to re- enable the admin permission only it will open.Cannot access folders and files even with Administrator rights and cannot backup also..

it is very too late process for every file and folder by changing the permission 
any help pls..

thanks in advance

Comment: Take ownership of the folders and files and then apply the desired permissions.

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks buddy. but i tried this ownership permission for folders.it is not changing to sub folders or files also, so i have to do manually for every folder or files to do so..